# emsdk error: LLVM IR bitcode is generated, bt not js/html

Tags: emscripten

I'm trying to compile an existing C++ project for webassembly using emscripten. Using em++ I was able to generate LLVM IR bitcode file, but not the js/html. I.e. when I try, for example `emcc project.bc -o project.html` I'm getting the following error:

```
LLVM ERROR: asm() with non-empty content not supported, use EM_ASM() (see emscripten.h)
shared:ERROR
```

Searching the web revealed no help. How do I trace back this error? Any advice please.

Comment: There seems to be assembly code directly embedded in the C++ code. This is not supported by emscripten.

Comment: @Philipp could you please explain more on that? How do I check that?

Comment: Search in your code for `asm(`. This is an [asm-declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/asm) used to directly add assembly code into your higher level c++ code. But since WebAssembly works differently and doesn't know what to do which these assembly instructions the Emscripten tool chain considers this as an error (as it might break your code when it's not there)

Comment: @Philipp thanks! Already tried to grep some asm instruction and to my disappointment there's :-( Thanks for you help, appreciate that. Could you please answer the question, not just comment it? Then I would be able to select your answer and close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to contain an [asm-declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/asm). This allows to directly embed assembly code into your C++ code.

Since WebAssembly works differently this assembly code is useless and this is why the compiler complains when it finds non-empty `asm()` statements (if they were empty the compiler would just omit them).

You can try and put this code into a conditional macro and see if the resulting WebAssembly code still works.

```
#ifndef __EMSCRIPTEN__
asm( stuff here )
#endif
```